# JavaScript refactoring / clean up

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Created this drawing app with JS / canvas. JSHint is throwing errors but the app works just fine. Need help with code clean up / refactoring as I'm fairly new to Javascript. Check out the snippet:

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in Advance!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.lineWidth = 5;
var down = false;
var xPos;
var yPos;

function draw(e) {
    xPos = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
    yPos = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

    if (down === true) {
        context.lineTo(xPos, yPos);
        context.stroke();
    }
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    down = true;
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(xPos, yPos);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    down = false;
});

function changeColor(color) {
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.fillStyle = color;
}

function clearCanvas() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changeBrushSize(size) {
    context.lineWidth = size;
}

function fillCanvas() {
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function changeBrushStyle(brushStyle) {
    context.lineCap = brushStyle;
}

function triggerClick() {
    document.getElementById('file').click();
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', function(e){
    clearCanvas();
    URL = URL || webkitURL;
    var temp = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = temp;

    image.addEventListener('load', function(){
        imageWidth = image.naturalWidth;
        imageHeight = image.naturalHeight;
        newImageWidth = imageWidth;
        newImageHeight = imageHeight;
        originalImageRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

        if (newImageWidth > newImageHeight && newImageWidth > 800) {
            newImageWidth = 800;
            newImageHeight = 800 / originalImageRatio;
        }

        if ((newImageWidth >= newImageHeight || newImageWidth > newImageWidth)  && newImageHeight > 500) {
            newImageHeight = 500;
            newImageWidth = 500 * originalImageRatio;
        }

        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, newImageWidth, newImageHeight);
        URL.revokeObjectURL(temp);
    });
});
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

html {
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  font: 16px/1 sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
blockquote,
figure,
ol,
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }

main,
li {
  display: block; }

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-size: inherit; }

strong {
  font-weight: bold; }

a,
button {
  color: inherit;
  transition: .3s; }

a {
  text-decoration: none; }

button {
  overflow: visible;
  border: 0;
  font: inherit;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer; }

::-moz-focus-inner {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0; }

:focus {
  outline: 0; }

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border: 0; }

section {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin: 20px auto; }
  section #canvas {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px auto 0px; }
  section #drawingTools {
    width: 800px;
    height: 135px;
    margin: 0 auto; }
    section #drawingTools #colors {
      width: 100%;
      height: 20px; }
      section #drawingTools #colors button {
        width: 20%;
        height: 20px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #7b1a86; }
        section #drawingTools #colors button:hover {
          opacity: 0.5; }
      section #drawingTools #colors #black {
        background: black; }
      section #drawingTools #colors #white {
        background: white; }
      section #drawingTools #colors #red {
        background: red; }
      section #drawingTools #colors #green {
        background: green; }
      section #drawingTools #colors #blue {
        background: blue; }
    section #drawingTools #otherTools {
      width: 100%;
      height: 115px; }
      section #drawingTools #otherTools button {
        width: 20%;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        border: 1px solid white;
        background: #303030;
        color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid #7b1a86; }
        section #drawingTools #otherTools button:hover {
          opacity: 0.6; }
  section #file {
    visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
  </head>
  <body>

    <section>
        <div id="drawingTools">
            <div id="colors">
                <button id="black" onclick="changeColor('black')"></button>
                <button id="white" onclick="changeColor('white')"></button>
                <button id="red" onclick="changeColor('red')"></button>
                <button id="green" onclick="changeColor('green')"></button>
                <button id="blue" onclick="changeColor('blue')"></button>
            </div>
            <div id="otherTools">
                <button id="clearCanvas" onclick="clearCanvas()">Clear canvas</button>
                <button id="brushSize1" onclick="changeBrushSize(5)">brush size 1</button>
                <button id="brushSize2" onclick="changeBrushSize(20)">brush size 2</button>
                <button id="brushSize3" onclick="changeBrushSize(30)">brush size 3</button>
                <button id="brushSize4" onclick="changeBrushSize(40)">brush size 4</button><br>
                <button id="fillCanvas" onclick="fillCanvas()">Fill canvas</button>
                <button id="defaultBrush" onclick="changeBrushStyle('butt')">default brush</button>
                <button id="squareBrush" onclick="changeBrushStyle('square')">square brush</button>
                <button id="roundBrush" onclick="changeBrushStyle('round')">round brush</button>
                <button id="openFile" onclick="triggerClick()">open img</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="canvas" width = "800px" height="500px;"></canvas>
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" />
    </section>

    <script src="assets/js/min/main-min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use JSHint and fix any errors - I even use `--show-non-errors` and clean those up too ... if you feel *your* code needs rewriting, then rewrite *your* code

Comment: I did use JSHint but could not figure out how to fix the issues... Hence the question / plea for guidance / help to more experienced programmers...

Comment: I know you used JSHint as I read the question, I merely suggested you fix the errors it reports - you haven't included that information

Comment: the only error is line 59 `URL = URL || webkitURL` ... change that to `var URL = URL || webkitURL`

Comment: Got it, apologies. Well the JSHint in Atom is fine but codekit (when compiles / minifies) says there are ew issues. For example: changeColor is defined but never used...(and many others that are using the onclick in the html); Also, URL = URL || webkitURL says read only and webkitURL is not defined; also imageWidth is not defined...

Comment: Clean-up and code review questions belong on the code review stack exchange. If there are actually development issues (I'm not entirely clear on what all you're asking) then reduce the problem to its basics and be specific. Good luck!

Comment: Ah ok, did not know - thank for letting me know!